# Disable Append button if there's a duplicate entry in jQuery

Tags: jquery, laravel

Hi I am just learning to code jQuery. How can I disable or probably do an alert if the entry is duplicate of another APPENDED row?

Here's my append row script

```
var rowCount = 1;

$('#add').click(function() {
    rowCount++;
    $('#orders').append('<tr id="row'+rowCount+'"><td><input class="form-control autocomplete_txt product_code" type="text" data-type="product_code" id="product_code_'+rowCount+'" name="product_code[]" for="'+rowCount+'" required/></td><td><input class="form-control autocomplete_txt" type="text" data-type="product_name" id="product_name_'+rowCount+'" name="product_name[]" for="'+rowCount+'"required/></td><td><input class="form-control product_price" type="number" data-type="product_price" id="product_price_'+rowCount+'" name="price[]" for="'+rowCount+'" required/></td><td><input class="form-control quantity" type="number" class="quantity" id="quantity_'+rowCount+'" name="quantity[]" for="'+rowCount+'" required/><span id="quantity_warning_'+rowCount+'"></span> </td><td><input class="form-control total_price" type="text" id="total_price_'+rowCount+'" name="total_price[]"  for="'+rowCount+'" readonly required/> <input class="form-control" type="hidden" data-type="product_id" id="product_id_'+rowCount+'" name="product_id[]"/><input class="form-control" type="hidden" data-type="order_id" id="order_id_'+rowCount+'" name="order_id[]" value="1"/></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+rowCount+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove cicle"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></button></td></tr>');
});
```

here's the screenshot of the form
[image]

**UPDATE**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="line line-dashed line-lg pull-in"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <h5><small class="text-danger"><em><strong>Type the first letter</strong> of the product code and in product name and wait for the dropdown to appear</em></small></h5>
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="orders">
      <tr>
        <th>Product Code</th>
        <th>Product name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Total Price </th>
        <th><a href="#" onclick="calculateSubTotal()" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark btn-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Recalculate"><i class="fas fa-calculator"></i></a></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="form-control autocomplete_txt product_code" type='text' data-type="product_code" id='product_code_1' name='product_code[]' for="1" required/></td>
        <td><input class="form-control autocomplete_txt" type='text' data-type="product_name" id='product_name_1' name='product_name[]' for="1" required/></td>
        <td><input class="form-control product_price" type='number' data-type="product_price" id='product_price_1' name='price[]' for="1" required/></td> <!-- purchase_cost -->
        <td><input class="form-control quantity" type='number' id='quantity_1' name='quantity[]' min="1" for="1" required/><span id="quantity_warning_1"></span></td>
        <td><input class="form-control total_price" type='text' id='total_price_1' name='total_price[]' for='1' readonly required/>
          <input class="form-control product_id" type='hidden' data-type="product_id" id='product_id_1' name='product_id[]'/>
          <input class="form-control product_id" type='hidden' data-type="order_id" id='oder_id_1' name='order_id[]' value="1" /></td>
        <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success circle"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    {{-- hidden inputs --}}
    <input class="form-control" type='hidden' id='user_id' name='user_id' value='{{ auth()->user()->id }}' /> 
    <input class="form-control" type='hidden' id='publish' name='publish' value='0'/>
    <input class="form-control" type='hidden' id='status_id' name='status_id' value='1'/>

  </div>
</div>
```

**2nd Update**
here's the jquery Autocomple script who's responsible for adding the products in my table

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//autocomplete script
$(document).on('focus','.autocomplete_txt',function(){
  type = $(this).data('type');

  if(type =='product_code' )autoType='product_code'; 
  if(type =='product_name' )autoType='name'; 
  if(type =='product_price' )autoType='price'; 
  if(type =='quantity' )autoType='quantity'; 
  if(type =='product_id' )autoType='id'; 

   $(this).autocomplete({
       minLength: 0,
       source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('searchaSaleItems') }}",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term : request.term,
                    type : type,
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    var array = $.map(data, function (item) {
                       return {
                           label: item[autoType],
                           value: item[autoType],
                           data : item
                       }
                    });
                    response(array)
                }
            });
       },
       select: function( event, ui ) {
            var data = ui.item.data;
            var arr = []; 
            id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
            id = id_arr.split("_");
            elementId = id[id.length-1];

            $('.product_code').val(data.product_code).each(function() {
              arr.push($(this).val());
            });
            $('#product_code_'+elementId).val(data.product_code);
            $('#product_name_'+elementId).val(data.name);
            $('#product_price_'+elementId).val(data.price).prop('min', data.price);
            $('#product_id_'+elementId).val(data.id);
            $('#quantity_'+elementId).prop('max', data.quantity);
            $('#quantity_warning_'+elementId).text('You have '+data.quantity+' in your stocks');
       }
   });
});
</script>
```

**3rd Update (problem solved)**

just sharing the adjusted answer from @chennighan

```
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      var data = ui.item.data; 
      var arr = []; 

      id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
      id = id_arr.split("_");
      elementId = id[id.length-1];

      $('.product_code').each(function() {
        arr.push($(this).val());
      });

      // added logic to check if there are duplicates in the array we just populated with product codes, checked against the passed in product code 
      if(arr.includes(data.product_code)) {
          $('#quantity_warning_'+elementId).text('duplicated');
      } else {
        $('#product_code_'+elementId).val(data.product_code);
        $('#product_name_'+elementId).val(data.name);
        $('#product_price_'+elementId).val(data.price).prop('min', data.price);
        $('#product_id_'+elementId).val(data.id);
        $('#quantity_'+elementId).prop('max', data.quantity);
        $('#quantity_warning_'+elementId).text('You have '+data.quantity+' in your stocks');
      }
    }
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: and what you will call a duplicate? when all the table cells data are the same for the given two rows?

Comment: Hi @HaiderAli the product code.

Comment: can you paste your table html so that i can construct the jquery snippet for implementing it.

Comment: Hi @HaiderAli I just updated my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a plain old JavaScript array.  When you add the row, you check if there are duplicates using the below logic on whatever trigger you need. If there are no duplicates and you're able to add the product with the product code, then you can add it to the `productCodes` array. If you need to make it persist through page loads, you can leverage `Web Storage` by saving it into either `local` or `session` storage.

```
// initially defined array to hold the product codes (can be toward the top of your javascript where constants and other top level vars are declared)
var productCodes = [];

/* 
    - when the trigger you're using is triggered to add the product code
        - you get the product code associated with what you've added
        - you call the isDuplicateProductCode function with that product code
    
*/

function isDuplicateProductCode(code) {
    // apply any other checking logic you need here

    // jQuery array method to check if the code passed to the function is in the productCodes array
    return productCodes.includes(code);
}
```

If it is a duplicate product code, as indicated by the above function, then you can apply any logic you want, for example: display an alert, pop a modal, display error/warning text that a different code must be used.

### UPDATE:

If you're already iterating the product codes and adding them to an array, you should just be able to add the above logic to check if there are any duplicates, and if there are, don't run the append logic. If there are no duplicates, continue on business as usual.

### UPDATE 2:

You can add this logic below your loop to check if there are duplicates and *only* append the items if it's not.

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
    var data = ui.item.data;
    var arr = []; 
    id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id_arr.split("_");
    elementId = id[id.length-1];

    $('.product_code').val(data.product_code).each(function() {
      arr.push($(this).val());
    });
    
    // added logic to check if there are duplicates in the array we just populated with product codes, checked against the passed in product code 
    if(arr.includes(data.product_code) {
        // at this point, this is a duplicate product code and you need to display your warning/alert/modal/text (whatever type you want)
    } else {
        // this logic is not executed because the product code is a duplicate
        $('#product_code_'+elementId).val(data.product_code);
        $('#product_name_'+elementId).val(data.name);
        $('#product_price_'+elementId).val(data.price).prop('min', data.price);
        $('#product_id_'+elementId).val(data.id);
        $('#quantity_'+elementId).prop('max', data.quantity);
        $('#quantity_warning_'+elementId).text('You have '+data.quantity+' in your stocks');
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you @ChrisHennighan. unfortunately I am just starting to learn to code javascript/jQuery, can you guide me thru this? shall I put the $('#add').click(function() {rowCount++;    $('#transfer').append(---); }); between the var productCodes = []; and function isDuplicateProductCode(code) {? and what shall I put in (code)? Also I am using laravel in this project

Comment: @Lito There are a few things to consider. To be able to make sure you're accounting for all of the product codes that may have come from the server (not sure if you're getting values from the server or if you're just adding new ones). If you're only adding new product codes, then you can just declare the array toward the top (when your js file loads). the `productCodes.includes(code)` is a jQuery array method that checks if the code is in the array. If that's all the logic you need you can leave that as is.

Comment: @Lito I have updated the initial answer with some more detailed comments.

Comment: the products are came from database and being fetch using jquery Autocomplete script. I think I should also share it here

Comment: it looks like you're already iterating over each of the product  codes when you're calling ```$('.product_code').val(data.product_code).each(function() {
              arr.push($(this).val());
            });```, so you can just add the logic to check duplicates before you start setting the properties below that loop.

Comment: this part,  $('.product_code').val(data.product_code).each(function() {arr.push($(this).val());}); is added just earlier as also suggested to me. but from here I don't know where else to go. How can I adopt your answer to my current codes? I am sorry I am not trying to get lazy i am really just stating to code.

Comment: No problem, I have updated the answer, check it out. Basically you're just going to add the logic to check if the array has the value that you're passing in.

Comment: It works!!! thank you so much @ChrisHennighan! Now I just need to modify the html side of it but the most important is now the form can recognize the duplicated entry.. thanks again!